# Navicat : Make a view and some field can be updated each time inputted

Tags: javascript, view, dreamweaver, mozilla, navicat

i have three table 
1. tbl_book
 - id_book (PK)
 - book
 - qty

2. tbl_borrow_book

   - id_borrow (PK)
   - id_book
   - qty_borrow
3. tbl_book_return

   - id_return (PK)
   - id_borrow

ok, here the question.

i want to make a view, when i input data in tbl_borrow_book then qty in tbl_book will be decreased.
and when i input data in tbl_book_return with the same book which was borrowed, then qty in tbl_book will be increased by the same qty.

thanks in advanced...sorry for bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you tagged it as a JavaScript, but I guess you are asking a SQL question. So I am going to answer it with a SQL solution

You can achieve your goal by using mysql trigger. Here is examples.

The following trigger will reduce the qty in `tbl_book` after you add any records to `tbl_borrow_book`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `book_borrowed` AFTER INSERT ON `tbl_borrow_book` 
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

UPDATE `tbl_book` SET `qty` = `qty` - NEW.`qty_borrow` WHERE `id_book` = NEW.`id_book` LIMIT 1;

END;
```

And the following trigger will increase the qty of book in `tbl_book` when there is any data inserted to `tbl_book_return`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `book_returned` AFTER INSERT ON `tbl_book_return` 
FOR EACH ROW 

BEGIN

DECLARE number_of_book, book_id INT;

SET number_of_book = 
(SELECT
    `tbl_borrow_book`.`qty_borrow`
FROM 
    `tbl_borrow_book` 
INNER JOIN `tbl_book_return` ON `tbl_borrow_book`.`id_borrow` = `tbl_book_return`.`id_borrow` 
WHERE
    `tbl_borrow_book`.`id_borrow` = NEW.`id_borrow` LIMIT 1);

SET book_id = 
(SELECT
    `tbl_borrow_book`.`id_book`
FROM 
    `tbl_borrow_book` 
INNER JOIN `tbl_book_return` ON `tbl_borrow_book`.`id_borrow` = `tbl_book_return`.`id_borrow` 
WHERE
    `tbl_borrow_book`.`id_borrow` = NEW.`id_borrow` LIMIT 1);

UPDATE `tbl_book` SET `qty` = `qty` + number_of_book WHERE `id_book` = book_id;

END;
```

Please note that although the 2nd trigger works, however, it is not optimized. The two SELECT statements may be combined into one. I will update this answer if I know how to do so.